# Parse Push Notifications add new Action

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uialertcontroller

If my app is open and i receive a push notification, there is only one action for the alert - "OK". Is it possible to add another action, similar to how i can do so for a UIAlertController as follows?

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Second Action", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
```

UPDATE: I have been looking around and it appears you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want in `Appdelegate.m`

```
- application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```

Just implement your code here.

Comment: But i want to set up a second action at the time when i send the push notification. Surely this function is called when the notification is received, not sent?

Comment: Then I dont really understand your problem. Just make an alert, when you want after `PFPush sendPushInBackground` method

Comment: When the push notitfication is sent by parse, it has only one action and it is by default set to dismiss the uialertcontroller. I want to add a second action to the notification sent by parse, such that i can for example have two actions. One action to dismiss and another action to segue to a specific screen

Answer (score 0):

Comment this `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` method in `- application: didReceiveRemoteNotification:`, and give customised alert view as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; objective C? It is giving me an error

Comment: yes. in Objective-c. check this method is removed from code(if u r using swift also)

Comment: I am using swift. If i initialise the UIAlertController and present it, i get the error "Application tried to present modal view controller on itself."